# Showing progress on a command line C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code that runs in a command line application written in C++

```
std::string filename = m_arguments[1];
unsigned long long size = stoll(m_arguments[2]);
char character = m_arguments[3].c_str()[1]; 

FILE *pFile;
if( (pFile = fopen(filename.c_str(), "wb")) != NULL)
{
  for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
  {
    fputc(character, pFile);
    unsigned long long  per = 100*i/size;
    if(per % 10 == 0) { cout<<"\r"<<per<<"%"<<flush; }
  }
  fclose(pFile);
}
cout<<endl;
```

The percentage flickers on the command line. I tried to reduce that flicker with `if(per%10 == 0)` but nothing changes. What can I do to stop that flickering?

Comment: You can try setting the cursor position rather than clearing the output each time.

Comment: You can dump the `\r` and simply print a trail of dots or something, which is just as pleasing and informative.

Comment: my task is to show the progress in percentage

Comment: If you work on Windows you could use my cppconlib library for things such as setting the text position, so you simply overwrite the previous text https://cppconlib.codeplex.com/.

Comment: yes, I am working on windows. but a library is my only choice?

Comment: @MariusBancila He is only overwriting the previous text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing you can do is to only display the percent if it changed since the last loop. This will minimize the amount of output you do to the console which is also slowing you a lot since its very inefficient.
Also fixed the loop variable type.

```
    std::string filename = m_arguments[1];
    unsigned long long size = stoll(m_arguments[2]);
    char character = m_arguments[3].c_str()[1]; 

    FILE *pFile;
    if( (pFile = fopen(filename.c_str(), "wb")) != NULL)
    {
      int last_per = -1;
      for(unsigned long long i = 0; i<size; i++)
      {
        fputc(character, pFile);
        int  per = (int)(100*i/size);
        if(last_per != per) { cout<<"\r"<<per<<"%"<<flush; last_per = per; }
      }
      fclose(pFile);
    }
    cout<<endl;
```

Comment: i get the same flicker

Comment: well you shouldn't... unless the file is very small and it goes really fast from 1 to 100, but that is to be expected. this code should only print the percent a maximum of 100 times no matter the size of the file. did you copy the assignement last_per = per inside the if block?

Comment: @zarzare He was originally only outputting when `per % 10 == 0`.  Adding this test (in addition to yours) should mean that he updates only 10 times during the run.  But given that he's using `'\r'`, there shouldn't be an flickering, regardless of how often he updates.

Comment: my file isn't small at all. it is about 2 to 10GB

Comment: @James using the test per % 10 == 0 means that it will write it a lot of times when the percent is 10 for example so it doesn't realy make any sense. the percent can be 10 for a really long time.

Comment: @zarzare That's why I said to use both tests.  Keep track of the last output value, and only output if that changes.

Comment: @James you shouldn't get a flicker from updating every percent.

Comment: @Victor try replacing the \r with \n in the output to see what actual values you get displayed. you should only get 100 values at most. if that's not true there is a problem with the code.

Comment: @zarzare, with `\n`, there are written the values from 0% to 99%

Comment: @zarzare You shouldn't get a flicker when updating every byte.  You're overwriting a character with the same character, and any flicker can only be due to an error in the rendering software.  (And yes, I know, you do get a flicker in a windows console window.  Which proves that the Windows console window is broken.)

Comment: @James Just for the sake of the argument the flicker can be from the cursor keep changing the position :)

Comment: @zarzare The flicker I saw wasn't just the cursor; it involved complete characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just playing around, but with:

```
int i = 0;
while ( i != 100 ) {
    i += 10;
    std::cout << '\r' << std::setw(2) << i << '%' << std::flush;
    Sleep( 2000 );
}
std::cout << "\rDone" << std::endl;
```

I couldn't see any flickering.

The problem in your case is that your only test is for `per % 10
== 0`.  If the file is big, you'll end up outputting each value
an enormous number of times, after each each byte you transfer.
If the file is 100KB (not really very big), this will output for
every byte between 0 and 999, then for every byte between 10000
and 10999, and so on.

This *shouldn't* flicker either, but some trials I did in
a standard Windows console window shows that it does.  And even
if it didn't flicker, it will slow things down enormously.  You
should be memorizing the last output, however, and only
outputting when it changes:

```
int lastOutput = -1;
for ( ... ) {
    //  ...
    if ( per % 10 == 0 ) {
        int toOutput = 100LL * i / size;
        if ( toOutput != lastOutput ) {
            std::cout << '\r' << toOutput << '%' << std::flush;
            lastOutput = toOutput;
        }
    }
}
```

This can be done much more efficiently, however.  For only ten
outputs, I'd probably create a table with ten entries,
indicating the values of `i` for which I want to output, and
check against this.